# Finding all shortest paths between two nodes in NetworkX

Tags: networkx, graph-theory, shortest-path

Assume I have a BA network with N nodes where each node has at least 2 edges. The network is unweighted. I am trying to find all the shortest paths between every node `i` and `j` for all nodes in the network. But if there are more than 1 shortest path between node `i` and `j`, then I need every single shortest path between `i` and `j`.

So if node 2 can be reached from 0 by using the paths `[0,1,2], [0,3,4,2], [0,3,4,5,2], [0,4,5,2]` and `[0,3,2]`, I need a list that says `[[0,1,2], [0,3,2]]`.

Is the only way of doing this is calculating each path from i to j and getting the smallest lenghted lists? Can this be founded in a more efficient way?

Edit: Apparently there's a path finding method called [all_shortest_paths](https://networkx.org/documentation/networkx-1.9/reference/generated/networkx.algorithms.shortest_paths.generic.all_shortest_paths.html). I will try this and see if it is efficient.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`nx.nx.all_shortest_paths`](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/algorithms/generated/networkx.algorithms.shortest_paths.generic.all_shortest_paths.html#networkx.algorithms.shortest_paths.generic.all_shortest_paths) for this:

> all_shortest_paths(G, source, target, weight=None, method='dijkstra')

Which allows you to specify a source and target nodes. Here's a simple example:

```
plt.figure(figsize=(6,4))
G = nx.from_edgelist([[1,2],[2,3],[7,8],[3,8],[1,8], [2,9],[9,0],[0,7]])
nx.draw(G, with_labels=True, node_color='lightgreen')
```

[image]

```
list(nx.all_shortest_paths(G, 2, 8))
# [[2, 1, 8], [2, 3, 8]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Floyd Warshall algorithm is that what you need

Comment: The documentation says the output is a dictionary of distances but I need specific paths, how can I get it by using it?